# Azure Function App Service Bus topic ImportError module c_uamqp

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-python-sdk

I hope somebody can help me to understand what I am doing wrong with this azure function.

My idea is structure as follow.

I have 2 topics. TOPIC_A is designed to receive a message and process it and send it to TOPIC_B which I want just to have that message until when I will decide what to do with it.

and this is the actual azure function app code.

```
import logging
import json
import boto3
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import azure.functions as func

def main(message: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    # Log the Service Bus Message as plaintext
    message_content_type = message.content_type
    message_body = message.get_body().decode("utf-8")

    logging.info("Python ServiceBus topic trigger processed message.")
    logging.info("Message Content Type: " + message_content_type)
    logging.info("Message Body: " + message_body)

    #KeyVault Configuration
    KeyVault_Url = f'keyvailt_url'
    Keyvault_Name = 'keyvalt_name'
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    client_keyvault = SecretClient(vault_url=KeyVault_Url, credential=credential)
    
    # Service Bus Connection string
    CONNECTION_STR = client_keyvault.get_secret("Service-CONN").value
    # For receiving the feedback from campaigns
    TOPIC_NAME_A = "topicAname" 
    SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = "subscriptionName"

    # For sending feedback and results of sentiment analysis and language detection
    TOPIC_NAME_B = "topicBname" 


    comprehend = boto3.client(service_name='comprehend', region_name='eu-west-1', aws_access_key_id=client_keyvault.get_secret("ID").value, aws_secret_access_key=client_keyvault.get_secret("SECRET").value)

    servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR)
    with servicebus_client:
        receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(
            topic_name=TOPIC_NAME_A,
            subscription_name=SUBSCRIPTION_NAME
        )
        with receiver:
            received_msgs = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=5)
            

            for msg in received_msgs:

                message= str(msg)
                res = json.loads(message) 
                text = res['Text']
                result_json= json.dumps(comprehend.detect_sentiment(Text=text, LanguageCode='en'), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
                result = json.loads(result_json) # converting json to python dictionary

                #extracting the sentiment value 
                sentiment = result["Sentiment"]

                #extracting the sentiment score
                if sentiment == "POSITIVE":
                    value = round(result["SentimentScore"]["Positive"] * 100,2)

                elif sentiment == "NEGATIVE":
                    value = round(result["SentimentScore"]["Negative"] * 100,2)

                elif sentiment == "NEUTRAL":
                    value = round(result["SentimentScore"]["Neutral"] * 100,2)
                    
                elif sentiment == "MIXED":
                    value = round(result["SentimentScore"]["Mixed"] * 100,2)

                lang_result=json.dumps(comprehend.detect_dominant_language(Text = text), sort_keys=True, indent=4)

                #converting languages detection results into a dictionary
                lang_result_json=json.loads(lang_result)

                #Formatting the score from the results
                for line in lang_result_json["Languages"]:
                    line['Score'] = round(line['Score']* 100, 2)
                
                #storing the output of sentiment analysis, language detection and ids in a dictionary and converting it to JSON
                output={
                'ID':res['ID'],
                'userId':res['userId'],
                'defID':res['defID']
                }

                output_json = json.dumps(output, ensure_ascii=False)
                
                #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                # Sending the processed output (output_json) in json format to another service bus

                def send_output(sender):
                    message = ServiceBusMessage(
                    output_json,
                    content_type="Analysis", #setting the content type so that the service bus can route it.
                    application_properties={b'CODE':msg.application_properties[b'CODE']} #setting the tenant code
                    )
                    sender.send_messages(message)
                    

                servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)

                with servicebus_client:
                    sender = servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME_B)
                    with sender:
                        send_output(sender)

                receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

Before to explain the issue I have with the function, I will explain what happen if I run this code locally.

If I send a message to the TOPIC_A, and head to that topic from azure portal, I can see the message in the RECEIVED tab, once I run my python code, that message from TOPIC_A get consumed and sent to TOPIC_B, where it stays in RECEIVED. And this is exactly the output I am expecting.

Now, I moved the entire logic under an azure function, I send the message to TOPIC_A..and instantly I see the message ending under DEADLETTERS, and in my azure function I get this error.

```
Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'c_uamqp' from partially initialized module 'uamqp' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/uamqp/__init__.py). Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack
```

while if I peek the message (TOPIC_A) in the dead letter I see this message:

```
deadletterreason "MaxDeliveryCountExceeded"
```

As far as I understand, is that the messages end so fast under dead letter, while my code is looking for the message under RECEIVED, it tries 10 times and then fails.

But the think that I am having trouble to understand, is why this is happening only when I use the azure function.

If anyone can help me to understand the problem, I will be great full.

Please if you need anymore details, just let me know.

UPDATE:

After different debug process, I can surely say that the issue is due to the `uamqp` but I don't understand why is not working.

I am running my pipeline on a ubuntu worker.

my requirement.txt has:

```
azure-functions
azure-servicebus==7.0.0
boto3
azure-keyvault
azure-identity
uamqp
```

and in the pipeline output I can see that has been installed

`uamqp-1.4.3`

but yet I am getting the same exact error:

```
Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'c_uamqp' from partially initialized module 'uamqp' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/uamqp/__init__.py). Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 305, in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 42, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 83, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/site/wwwroot/myfunction/testServiceBus.py", line 4, in <module> from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/servicebus/__init__.py", line 6, in <module> from uamqp import constants File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/uamqp/__init__.py", line 12, in <module> from uamqp import c_uamqp # pylint: disable=import-self
```

At first, my function was running from a `__init__.py` as default file created by visual studio code. So I thought it might be a name clashing. So I changed my file name to `testServiceBus.py` but I still have the same error.

this is my full configuration.

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "testServiceBus.py",
  "entryPoint": "main",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "message",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "XXX",
      "subscriptionName": "XXX",
      "connection": "XXX"
    }
  ]
}
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false
      }
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

thank you very much for any help or hint, totally lost here and I have no more ideas to try

Comment: I feel like I am getting closer. I am not sure how to test this but I believe is a conflict issue between the import azure.service and the `fund.ServiceBusMessage`

Comment: You can refer to a similar open issue on GitHub: [Azure Function Service Bus ImportError: cannot import name 'c_uamqp' from partially initialized module 'uamqp'](https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-python/issues/281)